# FOSS, Gratis, at-least-web-browser-operated, well-attested, generally considered as secured (and desirably standard) stock trading/investment program

Tags: gratis, open-source, finance

FOSS, gratis, at-least-web-browser-operated (but may also be natively-operated), well-attested, generally considered as secured (and desirably standard) stock trading/investment program.

The program should allow the user to insert hers/his bank account details and buy/sell stocks internationally with the money from selling any stock going directly to the bank account of the seller.

The option to simply becoming a shareholder in any company which needs finance, simply buying and simply selling.